# Jenkins unable to create file on unzip

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to use unzip command in jenkins execute shell but its not creating new directory.

I have tried using 7z but its not accessible during cp commands in jenkins.

```sh
sudo -S unzip -o /home/ubuntu/dist.zip
sudo cp -r /home/ubuntu/dist/* /var/www/html/
```

I want to unzip specific file and copy contents to a custom location.

Comment: Sorry problem is resolved as I was executing via jenkins shell it was unzipping to a custom location. I provided -d /path/to/location in unzip command and it worked fine.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark as answered :)